# Did I laplace tranform this unit step function correctly?

Tags: laplace-transform

$$L(t^3U(t-2))$$
$$L((t-2)^3U(t-2))$$
$$e^{-2s}L((t-2)^3)$$
$$e^{-2s}L(t^3-6t^2+12t-8)$$
$$e^{-2s}(\frac{3}{s^4}-\frac{12}{s^3}+\frac{12}{s^2}-\frac{8}{s})$$

There's my procedure above, is this correct? if not..where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis in the OP is flawed. Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}(t^3u(t-2))&=\int_2^\infty t^3 e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty (t+2)^3e^{-s(t+2)}\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-2s}\int_0^\infty (t+2)^3 e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-2s} \mathscr{L}((t+2)^3)
\end{align}$$

Now, simply use $(t+2)^3=t^3+6t^2+12t+8$ along with $\mathscr{L}(t^n)=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$.

Comment: @Modrisco The unit step $u(t-2)=0$ for $t<2$.  In the integral $\int_2^\infty t^3e^{-st}\,dt$, enforce the substitution $t=t'+2$.  Then, when $t=2$, $t'=0$.

Comment: So you simply shift the function to the left by 2 first?

Comment: Note that the function $t^3u(t-2)=((t-2)+2)^2u(t-2)=t'^3 u(t')$, where $t'=t-2$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark